# Printing a string which is formed by taking each successive letter in the list of words based on the position of the word?

Tags: python, list

For example:

list = ['how', 'are', 'you', 'today']

output:
hrua

printing the index0 of the first word and index1 of second word and so on...

please help!:(

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and lambda function:

```
result = lambda list: [item[i] for i, item in enumerate(list)]
```

Or as a normal function

```
def bar(list):
    return [item[i] for i, item in enumerate(list)]
result = bar(....)
```

This returns the letters in a list. If you want to print them:

```
l = ["how","are","you","today"]
for index, value in enumerate(l):
    print(value[index])
```

You need to consider that this does not check for validity. If we look at the array:

```
["a", "b"]
```

This will return an error, as "b" only has index 0, and no index 1.

Comment: thankyou so much for your kind explanation!!

Is there any way of doing this using a nested for loop?

Comment: @Ashley why do you need a nested for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l = ["how","are","you","today"]
"".join([x[i] for i, x in enumerate(l)])

# Output
# 'hrua'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `enumerate` function is your friend [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
l = ["how","are","you","today"]
for index, value in enumerate(l):
    print(value[index])
```

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation!! :)
but when i do this, it came back with the output: hruaNone
any idea why??

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce the output you described in any online or on device interpreter. Since the other answers provided similar solutions, check theirs, as those should definitely do the trick :)